# Use alternative font for specific character

Tags: html, css, fonts

We're currently using the following font rule:

```
body {
    font-family: Meiryo, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

This works nicely. There's only one problem: since Meiryo is a Japanese font, the code point for `\` is `¥`. This causes problems with emoticons like `¥o/` or `¯¥_(ツ)_/¯`.

I'm wanting to experiment with `@font-face` and `unicode-range` to use Verdana's `\` even when Meiryo is active.

I've tried various combinations of the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Meiryo;
  src: local(Meiryo);
}
@font-face {
  font-family: Meiryo;
  src: local(Verdana);
  unicode-range: U+5C;
}
```

I... honestly don't know what it's doing sometimes. It looks like it's still using Meiryo, but bolded text is all wrong and the baseline has changed, which in turn affects line heights and the overall layout of the page in a chain-reaction kind of way.

I almost feel like I'd be better off doing a server-side "replace `\` with `<span style="font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;">\</span>`" kind of thing...

Are any of my attempts reasonable or are there other things I should try?

---

Here's a "workaround" I've come up with:

```js
(function fixBackslashes() {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false),
        node, offset, span;
    while( node = walker.nextNode()) {
        if( node.parentNode.className == 'bs') continue;
        if( (offset = node.nodeValue.indexOf('\\')) > -1) {
            node = node.splitText(offset);
            node.splitText(1);
            span = document.createElement('span');
            span.className = 'bs';
            span.style.cssText = // TODO: Move this to stylesheet
                "display:inline-block;" +
                "text-decoration:inherit;" +
                "transform:scaleX(-1);";
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(span,node);
            span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("/"));
        }
    }
})();
```

Basically, replace backslashes in text nodes with a forward slash mirrored horizontally. It works, for some definition of the word "works".

Comment: That is still a thing?! O_o I thought that was a bug in Windows codepages and such, which has been obsoleted by proper Unicode code points…

Comment: `<meta charset='utf-8'>` maybe?

Comment: @zer00ne No luck - the response headers already include `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` anyway.

Comment: I have updated the question with a "workaround", it doesn't seem very good XD

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Meiryo;
  src: local(Meiryo);
  unicode-range: U+0-5B, U+5D-10FFFF; /*exclude U+5C (the backlash)*/
}
body {
  font-family: Meiryo, Verdana, sans-serif; 
}
```

Since meiryo is now missing glyph for the backlash char, engine tries to render '\' by next fallback fonts, verdana.

Comment: That seems to do the same as my attempt, and causes issues with bolded text being weird.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol, the diff. is that you were opt-in the '\' for meiryo that should be opt-out for your case...